# Android Studio - How to specify "-jvm-target" option in Java/Kotlin module?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-module

Recently, I was trying to create a Java/Kotlin module for my Android application.
When I was creating Retrofit `Interceptor`, there was an error saying:

> Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option.

Here is the screen shot of the exact error:

[image]

I know how to set `-jvm-target` for my Android module. But I am not able to find an answer for how to set it in Java/Kotlin module.

---

Here is what I have already tried:

**[Solution 1 (Not Working)]**

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

compileKotlin {
    targetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
}
```

**[Solution 2 (Not Working)]**

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
}
```

Above code gave me following error:

> Could not find method kotlinOptions() for arguments

Answer (score 7):

I have the following in the build script for my Kotlin module, which works for my project:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    // your dependencies...
}
```

Comment: For future readers: this solution worked for me on Kotlin (non Android) module.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Better than specifying a version number in a string.

Answer (score -2):

New  gradle version support like this

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
```

Comment: And what about Kotlin?